# undefined index file

Tags: php, ajax

estoy eviando un formulario por ajax y no me quiere reconocer el input de tipo `file`, practimente he intentado todo.

cabe destacar que el boton del `submit` esta fuera del formulario para luego capturar el formulario con la etiqueta `form` de **html** que te permite capturar el formulario sin importar donde este.

he seguido algunas normas para capturar el **input** de tipo `file` al enviar el formulario al archivo **php** tales como `if(isset($_FILES['file'])){}` ,tambien estoy agregando la etique al formulario `entype="multipart/form-data"`,.

todos los input los captura ecepto el de tipo file no entiendo por que aqui les dejo lo que he intentado

**archivo.html**

```
  <fomr action="info.php" method="post" entype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
       <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" />
       <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" />
       <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" />
       <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
   </form>

    <!--luego el boton de submit se encuentra fuera de el fom por x razon-->
    <!--el form es capturado con la etiqueta form de html-->
    <button type="submit" id="send" form="form">ENVIAR</button>
```

**archivo.js**

```
    $("#send").click(function(){

         var form=$("#form");//capturar fomulario
         var nombre=$("#nombre").val();
         var apellido=$("#apellido").val();
         var correo=$("#correo").val();

       form.submit(function(e){

          $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax/info.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: fom.serialize(),
                    type:"JSON",
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"

  }).done(function(res){

         console.log(res)

  }).fail(function(){

         console.log(res)

    })

              e.preventDefautl();
            })
        })
```

**info.php**

```
<?php

   $nombre=$_POST["nomre"];
   $apellido=$_POST["apellido"];
   $correo=$_POST["correo"];
   $destino="";
//intente sin if (isset()) tampoco funciono
  if(isset($_FILES["file"])){

      $file=$_FILES["file"]["name"];

       $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"]
       $destino = "img/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$destino);

  }

echo json_encode(array(

                "nombre"=>$nombre,
                "apellido"=>$apellido,
                "correo"=>$correo,
                "file"=>$file
                     ))

?>
```

**error:** undefined index file

si lo ago sin tratar de capturar el input tipo file esto funciona a la perfeccio no entiendo que pasa espero y me pueda ayudar

Comment: Parece que se te ha olvidado capturar el contenido del file en tu función click del JS. Capturas todos menos ese, es posible que por ahí anden los tiros. Eso provoca que desde el PHP estés tratando de capturar un elemento que no le llega jamás.

Comment: primero que nada elimina el *<fomr action="info.php" ">*  elimina el action. y esta mal como tienes tu formulario. es <form> no <fomr>

Comment: Como se captura el input de tipo file en el ajax  @PHPMYGUEL

Comment: Tienes dos errores aquí: `<[fomr<-ERROR] action="info.php" method="post" [entype<-ERROR]="multipart/form-data" id="form">`, debe ser así: **`<form action="ajax/info.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">`** Luego, en Ajax, cuando vas a enviar archivos es mejor usar `FormData` en vez de `serialize`. Verás que puse correctamente la ruta en el `action`, puedes usar ese atributo del `form` para poner la `url` en Ajax.